# laravel belongsTo gives null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, eloquent

belongsTo relation in laravel is returning null

```
public function games(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Game');
  }
```

but when i provide key as argument it seems to work fine

```
  public function games(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Game','game_id');
      }
```

but as per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) `game_id` is itself is a default argument. What is the small thing i am missing here.

Thanks

Comment: This is more of a side note, but shouldn't that be `game()` since it belongs to a single game?

Comment: @ThunderBird can you provide the other side of the relation as well? Also any relevant parts to your database schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `belongsTo` side of the relationship builds the foreign key name based on the name of the relationship method. This behavior is different than the `hasOne`/`hasMany` side of the relationship, which uses the name of the class.

In this case, your relationship method is named `games`, so it will look for the foreign key field `games_id`. You can either provide the foreign key field as the second parameter, as you have shown, or you can rename your relationship method to `game()`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the name of your method "games" may be the issue. The assumption with a 1-to-many relationship is that the parent class is singular while the child is plural. Try changing the name "games" to "game" and the key argument shouldn't be required.

At this point, I'm guessing Laravel is thinking your id key would be "games_id".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was using `public` for defining variables. When I change to `protected` it worked.

```
public $fillable = [..class properties..];
```

changed to

```
protected $fillable = [..class properties..];
```